# PHP can't check if Magento admin is logged in subfolder with a script that works in the root folder

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I have a root folder `var/www/html/` where i have installed a `Magento 1.9.2.4` and then i have a subfolder (in the root folder) `var/www/html/xxx`. In the `root` folder i can use this `PHP` script to check if an admin is logged in:

```
define('MAGENTO', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));
require_once MAGENTO . '/app/Mage.php';

Mage::app('admin');
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'adminhtml'));

$session = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session');

if($session->isLoggedIn()){
    $user = $session->getUser()->getUsername();
    echo 'Logged in as ' . $user;
} else{
    echo 'NOT logged';
}
```

This script works perfectly in the `root` folder but if i make a copy of it(and change the path to `Mage.php` ofc) in the subfolder `xxx` it doesn't work.

When i check the `cookie` using Chrome dev tools it has the domain `.www.example.com` and the path `/`

Also when i check if `adminhtml` exists while in the root folder i get a `true` return but when i check it inside the subfolder i'm getting a `false` return even tho the path looks like `/` in Chrome dev tools.

What should i do to be able to check in the subfolder if an admin is logged in just like i'm able to check that in the root folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your script works inside the root folder but not in your subfolder/s you might want to check the settings inside Magento's admin panel:

**Admin Panel > System > Configuration > Web(under General)** and then choose **Session Cookie Management**

Remove the **www** in front of **Cookie Domain**(if it's up there because Magento will automatically add a **.**[dot] in front of cookie domain when the cookie is created) and set **Cookie Restriction Mode** to **No**.

Comment: It was the `www.` in front of the domain name... Thank you so much!